# spring yml file for specific environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have 3 `yml` files namely

- `application-default.yml` -> default properties, should be available
  in all profiles
- `application-dev.yml` -> properties only for dev
  profile
- `application-prod.yml` -> properties only for prod profile

When I start my boot application by passing the `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`,I am able to access the `application-dev.yml` specific properties.
But I cant get the properties defined in the `application-default.yml` files.
Following is my `application-dev.yml` file:

```
Spring:
 profiles:
  include: default

spring.profiles: dev

prop:
 key:value
```

Comment: Try renaming application-default.yml to just application.yml (that is the default).

Comment: I tried this, but still no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, here is what I did.

Created a file application-common.yml, put the common properties there.
Then in the application-{env}.yml files I put this on the top.

```
spring:
 profiles:
  include: default
```

Since I dont need to ever load the default profile specifically, this works for me!!!

Comment: Just curious, what changes compare to previous setup.  This look similar to what you have in your application-dev.yml previously.

Comment: You probably meant application-default.yml? Or did you use include: common?

Answer (score 36):

**TL;DR**

Just rename the **application-default.yml** file to **application.yml** and will work as you expect.

**Explanation**

According to [the description in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config), a file called **application-{suffix}.yml** is activated when you run your application with the profile which name matches with the suffix. In addition, the main **application.yml** is loaded by default so it's the perfect place to put common properties for all profiles. Alternatively, if you want to keep the name of your file as application-default.yml you can pass two profiles to your Spring Boot application:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=default,dev
```

This way you will activate two profiles and both properties files will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for you response, this too should work,I guess, as we are explicitly activating both the profiles. I will try this as well.

Comment: @Daniel Olszewski is there any option to name the yml or properties file other than application . say like `datasource.yml`

Comment: @Arunprasad Yes, but then you have to load it manually using `@PropertySource` annotation

Comment: @Arunprasad To change `application.yml` to `myapp.yml` (keeping also `myapp-{profile}.yml`) you need to `java -Dspring.config.name=myapp ...`   But bear in mind: the jar file probably contains `application.yml`; it would be ignored now; it's a major change; you cannot know what new settings would appear  there with a new jar version.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is:

Put common settings in `application.xml`, and in this file add:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev, pro, xxx...
```

all the profiles you want to activate.

So that you just edit this file to switch environment.

Remember that external files procedes, so you can leave another `application.xml` outside of the WAR to activate `dev`/`pro`/... environment instead of editing this file every time. Be sure to check the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: The example is strange. You're activating both dev and production environment at the same time? Either I'm missing something or the answer is unnecessarily confusing for people just learning about this.

Comment: Well that's example. Should be `dev, dev-db, test-data...` or so. Just the idea.